# Parsing MySQL output to JSON extracting field names

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

I'm getting some trouble with parsing the output of MySQL query in order to feed Highcharts. The biggest problem is that I would hawe 100+ data series, and I would like to don't refer to each column name in the parsing process, now the desired output would be something like that:

```
[
{'name':'TS','data':[4349,4375]}
{'name':'time1','data':[503,573]}
{'name':'time2','data':[500,506]}
{'name':'time3','data':[508,649]}
]
```

But I'm stuck with this output, where all the data are printed in the only first array:

```
[
{'name':'TS','data':[4349,503,573,500,4375,506,508,649,]}
{'name':'time1','data':[]}
{'name':'time2','data':[]}
{'name':'time3','data':[]}
]
```

The PHP code that I'm using is the following:

```
<?php
  try {
    $con= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', "root", "");
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = "SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TS) as TS, TIME_TO_SEC(time1) as time1, TIME_TO_SEC(time2) as time2, TIME_TO_SEC(time3) as time3 FROM time ORDER BY TS";
    //first pass just gets the column names
    print "[";
    $result = $con->query($query);
    //return only the first row (we only need field names)
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //second query gets the data
    $data = $con->query($query);
    $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($row as $field => $value){
        print "{'name':'$field','data':[";
        foreach($data as $row){
            foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
                print " $value,";
            }
        }
    print "]}";
    }
    print "]";
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Any suggestion to how to solve that problem?

Comment: You are using `$row` inside the `foreach` that is iterating over it

Comment: And how can I iterate trough the columns? Because the FETCH_ASSOC seams to refers only to the rows

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using `$row` multiple times causing the loops to create errors.
Rename your inner `$row` variable to something else, e.g. `$innerData`.

```
foreach ($row as $field => $value){
        print "{'name':'$field','data':[";
        foreach($data as $innerData){
            foreach ($innerData as $name=>$innerValue){
                print " $innerValue,";
            }
        }
    print "]}";
    }
```

But there seem to be more problems in your code.
You query the database with the $query, 2 times. You you would get 2 same result sets. Did you miss to insert the second query statement ?

Please include the results the queries will produce in mysql, without php. This way I can improve my answer or other may help you too.

Comment: I'm still getting the same result as before

Comment: It was intended just to assign the mysql output to another variable.